# Table doesnt seem to have been created for yesterday

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I use Google Data Studio for my reporting and today's report (which has stats and details for yesterday) was broken and all stats were showing 0.
When I jumped on the BigQuery Console and tried to pull data for yesterday it threw an error saying no table exists

My query to do a quick check

```
select count(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id)
FROM `mytable.events_20200121`
where event_name = "user_engagement"
```

Error

```
Not found: Table mytable.events_20200121 was not found in location US
```

Usually never ran into this situation. Can someone please help out?

Comment: If you are certain there should be data for yesterday, and it doesn't show up within 24 hours, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I shall do that